# How to get the literal value of a TemplateHaskell named variable

Tags: haskell, macros, metaprogramming, interpolation, template-haskell

If I have a [`Name`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/template-haskell/2.7.0.0/doc/html/Language-Haskell-TH.html#t%3aName) in TemplateHaskell and want to find out the value of the variable that it names, provided that the variable is declared as a literal, can this be done?

```
var = "foo"
-- Can `contentsOf` be defined?
$((contentsOf . mkName $ "var") >>= guard . (== "foo"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, yes. In practice, no.

Finding out stuff about existing names is done using `reify :: Name -> Q Info`, and for a definition like that you would get back a `VarI` value, which includes a `Maybe Dec` field. This would seem to suggest that you might in some cases be able to get the syntax tree for the declaration of the variable, which would allow you to extract the literal, however [current versions of GHC always returns `Nothing` in this field](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell#What_can_reify_see.3F), so you're out of luck for a pure TH solution.

However, TH does allow arbitrary IO actions to be run, so you could potentially work around this by loading and parsing the module yourself using something like [haskell-src-exts](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts), however I suspect that would be more trouble than it's worth.